# For loop and If statement Excel VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement

I would really appreciate if you could help me out with this problem. I am trying to get vba to provide me all the numbers in increment of 1 from  1 to a value in cell G1 and populate it into column C. Afterwards, I want vba to check each cell in column C starting from C1 to see if the value is greater than a number  and to populate into the column next to it( Column D1 onwards )

For example, cell G1 has the number 5.

So, I should see the following in column c , which are the 1, 2,3,4,5 and in column D I should see only the value for cells greater than say 3. So that means only the value 4, and 5 is populated in columnn D.

I would appreciate any help as I am quite new to VBA and am trying to get a hang of it.

Thnx.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code? What exactly doesn't work for you. Please check [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub elyas()
    Dim i As Long, MagicNumber As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    MagicNumber = 3
    k = 1
    
    For i = 1 To [G1]
        Cells(i, "C").Value = i
        If i > MagicNumber Then
            Cells(k, "D").Value = i
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That is great gary, but is there a way to ensure that the answers in column D are populated next to the corresponding cell of Column C. Your solution populates Column D starting from D1 instead of D4 where the value 4 onwards begin. In other words,  Column D for the value 1,2,3 are blank but the the remaining are populated adjacently to Column C.

Comment: Hey Gary, i figured it out. All I did was to edit the value of 
  K=1 to
  K=MagicNumber + 1

Thnx a lot!: :-)

Comment: @elyas ..............Good Job!......................